# (ReactAssign firebase snapshot to a variable outside of the function

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Hi i am trying to get the data from my database, in componentDidMount(), it works fine with this :

```
componentDidMount() {
  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).once('value').then(function(snapshot) { 
      var valeur = snapshot.val();
      return valeur;
  });
  this.setState({userData:valeur});
}
```

I just want to know how can i assign this data to a variable that can be use outside of this function, i tried setstate and using variable that i declare outside nothing work i get :react native possible unhandled promise rejection (id 0) Typeerror: this.setState is not a function. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the anonymous function that you're passing to `.then` to an arrow function to allow you to use the `this` from the class scope.

Plenty of information [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485) on this

Comment: how can i do this ?

Comment: instead of `.then(function(snapshot) {....` use `.then(snapshot => {....` and then you can call setState

Answer (score 1):

You have to setState inside the .then function.

Then you can access your value with `this.state.userData.`

It will be undefined just after mounting then defined when your fetch resolves, so integrate a mechanism that checks for that.

For your undefined problem, a simple solution would be that for instance:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>{this.state.userData && this.state.userData.photo}</View>
    )
}
```

Edit: also like Kai pointed out I am not sure you have access to `this` instance inside `.then` callback if you don't use arrow notation.

Comment: Yes i work now but its undefined so what kind of system do you mean ?

Comment: Can you console.log snapshot .val to be sure it s defined pls? Inside the .then

Comment: yes it work inside the then but not outside i think its cause it execute it before the .then end so is there a way to wait for the .then to finish before keep on going through the code

Comment: Show all your code pls and put console.log(this.state.userData) in your component

Comment: Thanks, try using componentDidMount instead of WillMount. From React doc: ```Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.```. Also WillMount is considered deprecated

Comment: It change nothing i think i have to use async and await but i don't know how

Comment: async/await is just another way to write asynchronous code. .then() is fine for a single fetch like you are doing.

Comment: So why it didn't wait for the call to end ?

Comment: put your console.log(this.state.userData) just before the return() and not at the end pls. Be careful, the return() not the render()

Comment: Yes i know it work but the when the app is anitialize the setstate is not done so i can't access the state directly

Comment: Yes that's why you have to put logic before accessing it, for instance you can do: `render(<div>{this.state.userData ? this.state.userData : 'We are loading your information...'}</div>)`. You can also just do `{this.state.userData && put whatever you want to do with defined userData here}`

Comment: Yes state.userData won't be defined until .then() fires. But React will refresh automatically the component when it gets defined, this is the purpose of .setState.

Comment: Its defined as null, when i try to use the data for exemple this.state.userDate.photo i get an error : photo is not defined

Comment: Yes, try my code just above. By doing `{this.state.userData && 'what you want to do with defined value here'}`. The `&&` checks that userData is not `null` nor `undefined` nor `empty string` before accessing it, so you won't get this error. You have to put it directly into your component. I will edit in my answer

Comment: You're welcome, React is hard to understand at the beginning but then it's a really robust framework, bye!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Search extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      isLoading: false,
      userData: null
   }
   this.searchedText = ""
   this.localData=null;
  }



  componentWillMount() {

    user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      firebase.database().ref('/users/' + user.uid).once('value').then(snapshot => {

      pro = snapshot.val()
      this.setState({userData: pro});

});


    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText().then(data => this.setState({ films: data.results }))
      this.setState({ 
       films: data.results,
       isLoading: false
      })


      console.log(this.state.userData)
  }


  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' />
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  _signOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }

  _displayDetailForFilm = (idFilm) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("FilmDetail", { idFilm: idFilm })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <StatusBar
        hidden = {false}
        backgroundColor="#F1D145"
        ></StatusBar>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._signOut()} style={styles.button} activeOpacity={0.8}>
          <Text style={styles.button_text}>Déconnexion</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{user.uid}</Text>

        <FlatList
        data={this.state.films}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) => <FilmItem film={item} displayDetailForFilm={this._displayDetailForFilm}/>}
        />
        {this._displayLoading()}
      </View>
    )
}
}


        this.setState({ isLoading: true })
        getFilmsFromApiWithSearchedText().then(data => this.setState({ films: data.results }))
          this.setState({ 
           films: data.results,
           isLoading: false
          })


          console.log(this.state.userData)
      }
```

Here is all the code i already do console.log(this.state.userData) it return null